# Using Tablesorter, how to load table with filter defined in a URL

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

With Tablesorter, is it possible to send an URL that can apply a desired filter.

Specifically, in the table there is a location column with a text searchable filter. I would like users to be able to enter a URL that contains the specific location they need to filter.

So the URL might look something like: http://www.webpage.com?location=SFO

Is this possible somehow?

Comment: Are you talking about jQuery plugin [Tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/)?

Comment: Yep, sorry for not clarifying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to accomplish this by using:

$('table').find('input.tablesorter-filter').eq(0).val('name');      $('table').trigger('search', false);

Then had HTML insert the "name"

Answer (score 0):

I have a [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/) & pager with some ajax options that will allow you to pass filter info to the server. Check out [this demo](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-pager-ajax.html) - it's not attached to a database, so it doesn't really sort or filter, but you can see the attached url change.

If you are using the original tablesorter, it would still be possible to get it to work with a third party filter plugin. Please share which plugins you are using to get a more detailed answer.